# Mongo - most efficient way to $inc values in this schema

Tags: mongodb

I'm a Mongo newbie, and trying to make this schema work.

Its intended for logging events as they happen on a high traffic website - just incrementing the number of times a certain action happens.

```
  {
     _id: "20110924", 
    Vals:[
      { Key: "SomeStat1": Value: 1},
      { Key: "SomeStat2": Value: 2},
      { Key: "SomeStat3": Value: 3}
    ]
  }
  ,
  {
     _id: "20110925", 
    Vals:[
      { Key: "SomeStat1": Value: 3},
      { Key: "SomeStat8": Value: 13},
      { Key: "SomeStat134": Value: 63}
    ]
  }, etc.
```

So _id here is the date, then an array of the different stats, and the number of times they've occurred.  There may be no stats for that day, and the stat keys can be dynamic.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve these updates, avoiding race conditions...so ideally all atomic.

I've got stuck when trying to do the $inc.  When I specify that it should upsert, it tries to match the whole document as the conditional, and it fails on duplicate keys.  Similarly for $addToSet - if I addToSet with { Key:"SomeStat1" }, it won't think it's a duplicate as it's matching against the entire document, and hence insert it alongside the existing SomeStat1 value.

What's the best approach here? Is there a way to control how $addToSet matches? Or do I need a different schema?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a bad schema, it's impossible to do atomic updates on it. Do it like this:

```
{
   _id: "20110924", 
  Vals: {
    SomeStat1: 1,
    SomeStat2: 2,
    SomeStat3: 3,
  }
}
```

or you can skip The `Vals` subdocument and embed the stats in the main document.

Comment: I don't believe that's valid json?

Comment: Problem I have with embedding in the main document is that deserialization to a strongly typed class (c# driver) is impossible I think.

Comment: opp sorry, fixing it. I don't think you *always* have to deserialize with the c# driver, there's surely a workaround.

Comment: Can probably get round the deserialization issue, but not ideal.  I'm not sure why my original schema should be considered "bad".  What if I later wanted to log something additional (say "AvgDuration") as well as "Value"?  In the revised schema that's not possible, so am still keen to find out the answer to my original query...

Comment: of course it's possible, mongodb is totally schema-less. your schema is bad, because you cannot do atomic updates.. it's that not enough? :)

Comment: Schema-less, but you still need to use one that work...so my question then becomes: how do you add "AvgDuration" and yet maintain atomic updates?

Comment: use `$set`. but please do not go to endless discussion, accept the answer and create a new question..

Comment: You say "use $set". Simply show me how to do an atomic update using $set, against the schema I provided in the original question, and I'll accept your answer gladly.

Comment: @Nik: I **told** you your schema is screwed, you cannot do atomic updates on it. Use a proper schema. That was my answer.

Comment: You said change schema. I explained why I wanted to keep an embedded document (AvgDuration) etc. and asked if that was possible. You said "of course its possible", but then refuse to demonstrate how (and seem incensed that I ask).  The AvgDuration schema is essentially equivalent to my original question.  So you've contradicted yourself about whether its possible. Either way "it's impossible" is not a great answer, so I'll see if anybody else cares to add something constructive. Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.danharman.net/2011/09/14/mongodb-and-c-dictionary-serialisation-part-1-the-problem/) which explains the issues around serializing a Dictionary using the MongoDB C# driver.  See also [this work item](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-311) on the C# driver.

Comment: "The nested array is not a well supported structure in mongo, and using it for dictionary persistence is very limiting. We lose the ability to search, index and update atomically." - thx, that's just proves my point.. that schema isn't suited for atomic updates. also that array doesn't really make sense, for this kind of storage you really need a dictionary. Is the C# driver really so bad? The python, ruby and php drivers all alow storing and retrieving arbitrary data.

Comment: The latest C# driver has a new `DictionarySerializationOptions` option to address this.

Comment: Thanks for those references @Hightechrider.